# Spring boot cannot set level 'WARNING' for 'null'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logging

When I start my server , developed with Spring boot, I get following error message right at the beginning, although my application starts properly in the end.

In my `application.dev.properties` I set `logging.level.root=WARNING` .

**ERROR:**

> ERROR 17356 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.l.LoggingApplicationListener     : Cannot set level 'WARNING' for 'null'.

Comment: Which logging framework do you use?

Comment: When I hover over my Logger class it says the following:

The org.slf4j.Logger interface is the main user entry point of SLF4J API.

Comment: Ok SLF4J is just a facade. Hm. In my pom.xml I do not find any logging dependency. I just took over this project. Where in spring boot can I find the logging framework used

Comment: When using starters it should be logback, but maybe it just reports before getting o this error? Or maybe you can find a logging configuration in the project :-)

Comment: If you use log4j2 this could be related: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/71

Comment: I just saw on wikipedia log level "Warning" is called "Warn" on most logging frameworks. So now I just configure logging.level.root=WARN  and I don't get an error. Hm I am not sure if this is right now

Comment: Yeah I use spring boot starter so it should be Logback framework which is automatically included